# What are the benefits of the internal Platform integration with using Platform Events?

Tags: automation, bestpractice, platform-event

I'm learning about the Event-driven Architecture from Trailhead, this unit to be exact: [Understand Event-Driven Software Architecture](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform_events_basics/platform_events_architecture). As in general I can say that the concept is pretty clear to me (also, [here's a great question in SFSE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244108/what-is-the-core-benefit-of-platform-events)), I'm not sure that I understand one of the scenarios presented in this unit - it's  a Platform to Platform "integration".

Here's a copypaste from Trailhead:

> **Platform to Platform: Reassign Lead Records**
>
> When a lead is assigned in Salesforce, a lead trigger fires and checks
> open opportunities and cases related to the lead owner. Based on the
> related records, the trigger publishes an event that is received by a
> Salesforce app. Based on the event information, the app reassigns the
> lead and creates a Chatter post.
>
> In this scenario, you can perform the same actions using other
> Salesforce features, such as Process Builder or flows. **But by using
> platform events, you benefit from an event-based programming model and
> a standard way of programming across your apps.**
>
> [image]

What I'm mostly stuck at, is that I couldn't find any useful information about the benefits from this approach, comparing to the conventional one - just by automating such processes via Flows/Apex. To me, it's even more problematic, as instead of keeping the whole process within one automation method, you divide it into two. I can imagine that for instance it could potentially  make debugging harder.

But maybe it's just a bad example? I'm aware that Platform Events / Push Topics and other event-based technologies work very nicely for updating the frontend with the usage of the `empApi` component.

But what about the backend-backend cooperation? What benefits you could identify, when it comes to implementing solutions such as the one described on the top in Salesforce?

Comment: Have you seen Architect Design Guides - [Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/data-integration) and [Event-Driven](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/event-driven) . They answer your question.

Comment: It is an example of how to implement separation of concerns. LHS (the trigger) says "something interesting has happened, I'll publish it out to anyone who cares". RHS (the PE consumer) is listening for this interesting event and then does something with it. LHS doesn't care what RHS does; RHS doesn't care who generated the event or why.